# Assign xp_cmdshell_proxy_account to [NT Authority\Network Service]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder if I can assign xp_cmdshell_proxy_account to [NT Authority\Network Service]. Basically, I want network users to execute xp_cmdshell without giving them sysadmin role.

I tried

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account [NT Authority\Network Service], 'password'
```

but I got error saying :An error occurred during the execution of sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account. Possible reasons: the provided account was invalid or the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential could not be created. Error code: '1326'.

I tried to run sql server as administrator too, but I got the same error.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I do know on this, is what I've done in the past on this.

I remember that it is possible to run xp_cmdshell using whatever valid system credentials desirable.
I also remember that I needed to have xp_cmdshell run windows scripts to get some files from a network location, such as `"\\somePC\c$\somefolder\*.*"` and to do this I needed the SQL Server windows service, to have it run by a valid account other than Network Service or Local Service etc. It needed a *normal* let's say, account. Otherwise it wouldn't work.